# DC User Plugin: re-login with Cookie fails

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am using DC User Plugin with activated "RememberMe" Cookie. If the session is expired and I reload a public page, it works fine (it gets the cookie and renews the session).

But if I reload a page (after session has expired) which is only allowed for logged-in users, it does not check the cookie and redirects me instead to the login page. But if I then click another (public) page and then go back to the user-only page - it works, too, without to have to login again.
So the RememberMe/Cookie Component itself seems to work fine.

My Code for the Auth check for the problematic user-only page is simple:

```
public function view() {
    if (!$this->Auth->user()) {            
        $this->redirect('/users/login');
    } else  {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

What do I have to add/change, so that it checks the User Cookie here, too, when the Session is expired? In the documentation of that Plugin I couldn't find that unfortunately.
Thank you so much for your help and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Well I resolved by myself. Allthough I had added

```
$this->RememberMe->restoreLoginFromCookie();
```

to beforeFilter() function in Controller, the function always returned false, because the Cookie saves email+password, but Standard Auth expects username+password.

I added

```
public $components = array(
...
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array( 
            'Form' => array(
                'userModel' => 'User',
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password'
                )
            )
        ),
...
```

so it will check for the needed email field, and now it works.